# A question about MKMapView Annotations

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

From documentation, the MKMapView property, Annotations, is a NSArray and not a NSMutableArray.  So Annotations is supposed to be "immutable". But MKMapView's instant methods  : addAnnotation and removeAnnotation are capable of changing the Annotations array.  So on the surface there seems to be some inconsistencies.  There must be something I have missed.  Hope that somebody knowledgable could shed some light on this.

Comment: I couldn't see inconsistencies or contradictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're meant to use `addAnnotation` and `removeAnnotation` to add/remove annotations instead of manipulating the annotations array directly.

I assume both those functions do some processing as well as adding/removing annotations from the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, am just wondering if the add and remove calls would somehow replace the old array with a new one.  As you say, we are meant to use the given methods, the assigned type is to prevent us from doing anything directly.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring the `annotations` property an `NSArray`, code that accesses the array *through that property* cannot safely modify it and must treat it as an immutable `NSArray`.  However, that doesn't mean that the array itself is immutable.

Here's an example of how something like this might work:

```
@interface MyObject
{
   // instance variables
   NSMutableArray* internalArrayRepresentation;
}

// properties
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray* immutableAccessor;

// methods
-(void)addItem:(NSObject*)object;

@end


@implementation MyObject

@synthesize immutableAccessor=internalArrayRepresentation;

-(id)init
{
   if ((self = [super init]))
   {
      // create the mutable array
      internalArrayRepresentation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
   }
}

-(void)addItem:(NSObject*)object
{
    [internalArrayRepresentation addObject:object];
}

...

@end
```

In this example, you can see that `internalArrayRepresentation` is a mutable array, and that its accessible outside of MyObject as `immutableAccessor`.  But because the property definition says that `immutableAccessor` is an `NSArray`, callers need to treat it that way and can't manipulate it.

There are other implementations that can accomplish this as well.

The typical reason to use a pattern like this is because you want `MyObject` to maintain control over the contents of the array: maybe only certain objects can be added, maybe objects need to be modified or cloned on the way in, maybe anything can be added but nothing can be removed, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer.  There are code patterns (such as the assignment in the “@sysnthesize” line) that I have never seen before.  But they must be code that are more advanced than anything I have encountered.  Thanks ...